# React Native prop doesn't work on second include

Tags: react-native

**I can display props correctly in a first level component, but when I try to display them in a second level component they don't appear.**

Main view:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import FirstComponent from '../components/FirstComponent';

import EditScreenInfo from '../components/EditScreenInfo';
import { Text, View } from '../components/Themed';

export default function SummaryScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <FirstComponent name="Phil" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

In a `FirstComponent`, `props.name` displays correctly as 'Phil', and calls my second component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text} from 'react-native';
import ShowName from './ShowName';

function FirstComponent(props) {

  return (
    <View>
    <Text>{props.name}</Text>
    <ShowName />
    </View>
  );
};

export default FirstComponent;
```

But in my `ShowName` component, nothing appears inside the div (the div itself renders correctly, however):

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

function ShowName(props) {

  return (
<div><Text>{props.name}</Text></div>
  );

};

export default ShowName;
```

Comment: You're not passing the prop `name` to the `ShowName` component. In the `FirstComponent` declaration, pass the `name` prop to `ShowName`: `<ShowName name={props.name} />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to forward the `name` prop from `FirstComponent` to `ShowName`.

```js
function FirstComponent(props) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{props.name}</Text>
      <ShowName name={props.name} />
    </View>
  );
}
```